# How to get the number of threads on the waiting queue for a cpu?

Tags: linux, process

Is there a way to programmatically get the number of threads waiting for cpu on Linux.

Comment: What do you need that number for? Is the load given by `uptime` good enough for you?

Comment: I want to calculate the load, and also to learn. That is enough motivation

Comment: @michas this type of number is important for capacity planning. Right-sizing our Linux hosts. uptime provides the backlog of the process run queue, not the thread queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the ps man page, the status field will tell you if a thread is on the run queue (use the 'L' option to see threads) --

```
  D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
  R    running or runnable (on run queue)
  S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
  T    stopped by job control signal
  t    stopped by debugger during the tracing
  W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
  X    dead (should never be seen)
  Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent
```